# using select() in client socket program

Tags: c, sockets

I was trying to write a server-client socket program in C. I'm having a question regarding how I achieve it using timers. What i'm trying to do is establish a connection between a server and a client and have a read-write operation. I came to know about using select() at the server end with the 'timeval' struct. But what should i do at the client end where I can read on a socket for a fixed amount of time.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "read on a socket for a fixed amount of time"? Do you want the client to be connected only for a limited time? Or do you want the client to time out if it doesn't receive anything for some time?

Comment: What have you tried? https://www.google.ru/search?q=c+socket+select+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly the same thing at the client, setting the timeout you want in the `select()` system call's `timeval` structure. But in a client it's easier to use blocking mode and use `setsockopt()` with the `SO_TIMEOUT/SO_RCVTIMEO` option, whatever it's called on your platform, to control the timeout. Check the *man* pages concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes exact if you want a short example of socket with "setsockopt":

```
int mySocket;
struct timeval tv = {0, 0}; // Init to 0 (Or set directly with your values)

mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
// Set the timeout (If you don't have set directly values)
tv.tv_sec = 10;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
// Set The Timeout On Socket RECV
setsockopt(mySocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
// Set The Timeout On Socket SEND
setsockopt(mySocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&tv, sizeof(struct timeval));
```

Comment: //sample client code        
        
        time_out.tv_sec = 15;    // 15 seconds
        time_out.tv_usec = 0;    // 0 milliseconds
        sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        n=connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        n=write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        n=read(sockfd,buffer,255);

The sample code above is what I'm trying to do- Connect to a server on socket 'sockfd' and first do a write operation and then a read operation. The read() has to wait for 15secs and then timeout but it doesn't. Need help!

Comment: Ok don't use read/write but send/recv functions i think !?
http://linux.die.net/man/2/send  http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv